# How to share Text in Twitter in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I use OAuthTwitterDemo and it gives Error [OAConsumer initWithKey:secret:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85b8dc0

And I use this Method for login ...

```
if (_engine) return;
_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
_engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

if (controller) 
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
else {
    [_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]];
}
```

But the login doesn't display and it gives an error ...

[OAConsumer initWithKey:secret:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85b8dc0 and crash App .

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code, It is working fine for me. Check your consumer key and consumer secret key.

```
if(!_engine){
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
        _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;
        _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  

    }

    UIViewController *controller =[SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

    if (controller)
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert both your kOAuthConsumerKey and your kOAuthConsumerSecret here:

```
_engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
```

If you don't it will crash.
The error you are getting, "[OAConsumer initWithKey:secret:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85b8dc0 and crash App", is pointing to the value of the kOAuthConsumerSecret, which has not been inserted.